# Resetting unknown E-Tube Passkey

Tags: shimano, electronics

I just bought an e-bike from Wiggle's demo fleet and am having problems with the electronics. I think I need to do a firmware update but I can't get into the E-tube app which allows me to configure the settings.

I tried using a passkey of "000000" to access the setting, but it didn't work and I don't know any other default passkey to try.

Is there a way to reset the passkey without knowing the current one?

Is there a recommended way to contact a Shimano for product support?

Comment: Hey John. Your question is really hard to follow. Could you add some punctuation, line break, and a little more detail?

Comment: I gather you're talking about this: https://e-tubeproject.shimano.com/?lang=en

Comment: With problems like this, the seller should be the first to contact.

Comment: You bought something from a shop. It doesn't work. You need to take it up with them. It doesn't matter that it's ex-demo, unless this specific issue was brought to your attention before you bought it.

Comment: @ojs I get that shops must help with faulty goods, but the question is still valid for anyone who forgets their passkey or buys a second hand bike for example, where consumer protections don't apply

Comment: John - did Wiggle help or were they dismissive of your problem/query?   This is one of the common differences between buying online and buying from a local bike shop.

Answer (score 5):

You can reset the Wireless passkey for **11-speed** Di2 - even if you don't know the current one - by connecting your bike to a windows computer/laptop using the charger. If you're on 12-speed Di2, you need a bike shop to change it for you.

Download e-tube for windows at https://e-tubeproject.shimano.com

**Important**: if you're using the charger, SM-BCR2, then the latest E-Tube Project version (V5 / Professional) will **not** work. You need version 3.4.5 or v4.0.4 from the archive page: https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/e-tube/project/archive.html

Personally I **prefer version 4.0.4**, especially since v3.4.5 no longer connects to the internet for firmware updates. However, in some occassions version 4.0.4 will complain that the SM-BCR2 firmware is 'old'. The fix for that is to download 3.4.5, and use that to connect to the bike once. Doing so will update the BCR2 firmware in the background.

Version 3.4.5 will complain that it cannot connect to the internet, but you can ignore that message and just click 'ok' and 'connection check'.

In v3.4.5 you change the passkey like this:

- Connect the bike to your computer using the charger and Junction A
- Open the e-Tube windows app
- Make a connection by clicking "connection check"
- Click "Bluetooth LE settings"
- Set a new passkey

If you're using v4.0.4, open the customize screen and then the EW-WU111 details page.

You can now use the passkey you just set to connect to your bike using BluetoothLE/ANT+. The Passkey is required for wireless connections only.

Also: if you really want to update firmware then I recommend using a computer (over USB) rather than the mobile app. It a bit safer. You *can* update using the mobile app, of course.. but as far as I'm concerned the mobile app's main feature is changing settings easily (out on the road).

More info:

- resetting your passkey: https://bettershifting.com/change-di2-wireless-passkey-using-mobile-e-tube-app-or-pc/  (2nd half of page)
- connecting to computer https://bettershifting.com/how-to-connect-your-di2-system-to-your-windows-computer/

(disclaimer: my website ;). If you're having more problems and can't figure things out don't hesitate to ask)

Comment: That's all well and good Terry but what if you don't have a PC?

Comment: If you don't know anyone with a Windows PC or a Laptop then I recommend you go to a shop if you really want to update firmware. It's not like you have to firmware every month ;).

Comment: Is the point here that you can reset the passkey, without knowing the existing one, while it is plugged in to a pc over a wired connection, and that the passkey is for wireless communication?

Comment: Yes! I'll clarify :}

Comment: cool beans, it was implied that if someone followed the instructions, they would have success, but I love me some clarity

Comment: Hey there.  I really appreciate the expertise you bring to these specialist questions.    Please keep it going.   And +1 for the full disclosure too.

Comment: Unfortunately does not work anymore with the original charger SM-BCR2 because Shitmano's F&%$ked up horrible support software (that they have made billions off of and helped give Sram a thriving business with electronic shifting.) All the tricks to connect using the older E-tube projects no longer work. So, only purchasing a brand new bluetooth unit such as Ew-Wu111. Btw, if you have a newer charger and it works for downloading software over the pc's wifi connection, do it that way and never update the firmware of your di2 shifters, etc, with the bluetooth unit.

Comment: You will most likely brick them and have to go to the dealer with the bike and have it re-flashed.

Comment: It works just fine with 11-speed Di2, but you need the 'older' version of the software, version 3.4.5 or 4.0.4. The version listed on the e-tube page is V5 and that won't work with the charger. I'll update the answer :)